# Applying probabilities to events

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

I recently thought about an example for a probabilistic graphical model that involved an alarm system for burglars. It roughly was a follows (it included an earthquake as well which is not relevant to my question though).

$\Pr(B=b\mid A=1) = \frac{\Pr(A=1 \mid B=b)\cdot\Pr(B=b)}{\Pr(A=1)} $

My question is about time-scales here. I think the easiest is to define that $\Pr(A=1)$ represents the probability of an alarm occuring **within a day** for example. But since burglaries are kind of "events" with a rather narrow time-span, I wonder whether this "binning" is the best idea. Is there aspecial way to deal with point-in-time-like events in probabilities?

Answer (score 0):

We can do Bayesian analysis any time we can assign meaningful number to the ratios of probabilities, even if the individual probabilities are infinitesimal. But no physical system truly works on point-in-times. There is some time period, even if it is microseconds, over which an event can occur. Also, if the size of the "bin" is small enough that the probability of two different events both triggering the alarm is sufficiently small compared to the probability of a single event triggering the alarm, then the ratios of probabilities will be about the same as if you used a smaller bin.